# I have an existing .apk of game and it is 30fps, how can i change from 30 to 60 fps?

Tags: android-studio, frame-rate

Developers. I am new to Android Studio, is there anyway to change framerate of choppy 30fps limited game? It is not made by Unity. I decompiled .apk also.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Application.targetFrameRate = 30;`.

https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Application-targetFrameRate.html